# SharePoint read-only field not visible for Records Center rules

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-type, site-column

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I have developed a SharePoint 2010 solution which creates a new content type. One of the new columns in that content type should not be visible in *Add New* and *Edit* forms, i.e:

```
<Field ID="{4E887808-B3CF-421D-AFAF-4E6A60A6890E}"
       Name="DocumentStatus"
       DisplayName="Document Status"
       Type="Text"
       ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
       ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
       Group="Custom Columns" />
```

The same content type is used for one Records Center rule. The rule specifies that once the `Document Status` field equals `"Completed"`, the document should be moved to a particular Records Center document library.

However, being that the `Document Status` field has the properties `ShowInNewForm` and `ShowInEditForm`set to true, I cannot see and pick the field from the list of content type columns while defining the rule.

Does anyone know how to make the field non-editable but still to be able to use it in the Records Center rules? My guess is that some other field properties need to be set for the field definition, but I am stuck. Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558288.aspx quote: "Available columns are always constrained to all non-hidden columns on the rule's content type" . I suppose you could not use a column not displayed in new/edit form in rules definitions.